# How to include a code block in JSF

Tags: jsf, include, block

**I want to include 'sample code' in a JSF page.**
Customers should be able to read this code and copy-paste this.
Any idea how to do this?

**It should look like this** code-block below here on StackOverflow:

```
<p:splitButton value="Save" update="messages" icon="ui-icon-disk">
    <p:menuitem value="Update" outcome="splitButton.xhtml" update="messages" icon="ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-w" />
    <p:menuitem value="Delete" outcome="splitButton.xhtml" icon="ui-icon-close" />
    <p:separator />
    <p:menuitem value="Homepage" url="http://www.primefaces.org" icon="ui-icon-extlink" />
</p:splitButton>
```

I don't find any good examples on this topic. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using Google Code Prettify. It consists of CSS and JS files and also has tons of color themes. Try putting your code in a message bundle and include it with:

**Messages**

```
test.pretty=<p:splitButton value="Save" update="messages" icon="ui-icon-disk">\n  ...
```

**XHTML**

```
<pre class="prettyprint linenums">
    <h:outputText value="#{messages['test.pretty']}" escape="true"/>
</pre>
```

**Output**

[image]

You can find the project [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/), and color themes [here](http://jmblog.github.io/color-themes-for-google-code-prettify/).

If you'd rather go small footprint, then you could use `<pre>` tag and own CSS.